Highlight particular word in python docx
I want to highlight the particular word in the paragraph of docx
Paragraph : English, with its twisty history and vast vocabulary, has become a global language. Borrowing words and morphing over centuries, it connects people across continents. though its rules can be tricky, English unlocks a world of literature, music, and ideas.
Here the font style are arial but word global has Times New Roman style
Here the font size are 12 but the word over has 15
I want to split the paragraph by the word though and I want to highlight the word though
I have done highlight word but the thing is the word global is changed to arial and word over size is changed to 12
but I want that word to be in the same state word global as Times New Roman and word over size is 15
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
for run in paragraph.runs:
    if run.font.name != None and run.font.name != 'Arial':
        run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 165, 0) #Orange
        run.font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW
    if(run.font.size != Pt(12) and run.font.size != None):
        run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 255, 255) #White 
        run.font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.GREEN
word = 'though'
for run in paragraph.runs:
              if(word in run.text):
                  new_paragraph = paragraph.text
                  paragraph.clear()
                  pattern = r'\b' + word + r'\b'
                  tempText = re.split(pattern, new_paragraph)
                  if(len(tempText)<2):
                      beforeRun = paragraph.add_run(tempText[0])
                  else:
                      beforeRun = paragraph.add_run(tempText[0])
                      currentRun= paragraph.add_run(word)
                      currentRun.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 255, 255) #White
                      currentRun.font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.BLUE
                      for i in range(1,len(tempText)):
                          if(i==len(tempText)-1):
                              afterRun = paragraph.add_run(tempText[i])
                          else:
                              afterRun = paragraph.add_run(tempText[i])
                              tempRun= paragraph.add_run(word)
                              run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 255, 255) #White
                              tempRun.font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.BLUE

Here is the output I expect :

This is what I get :


Can you show some sample code, what have you tried?

Can you show the part of your code where you take the data out from the docx file and highlight it? I could understand your problem better too. If possible, please attach screenshots of the before and after of your docx file so that i can clearly understand the issue here.

This can help: https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Python/Spire.Doc-for-Python/Program-Guide/Text/Python-Find-and-Highlight-Text-in-Word.html#:~:text=document.Close()-,Find%20and%20Highlight%20the%20First%20Instance%20of%20a%20Specified%20Text,CharacterFormat.
